# SAPUI5 - Table rerenders after data call

Tags: sapui5

I am using sap.m.Table to display some documents as a sap.m.Dialog.The UI looks as below:
[image]

Everything works as expected but when I scroll to the last Item (growing=true) the table rerenders and moves back to the top. Ideally that would happen only when I refresh a model. I am using bindAggregation to bind the odataModel to the UI. Please see a snippet below (Note:Partial  snippet).

```js
var dialog = new Dialog({
  title: title,
  buttons: [
    new sap.m.Button({
      text: "{i18n>close}",
      press: function(oEvt) {
        dialog.close();
      }
    })
  ]
});

var table = new sap.m.Table({
  width: "100%",
  inset: true,
  growing: true,
  growingThreshold: 100,
  growingScrollToLoad: true
})

dialog.addContent(table);
if (!dialog.isOpen()) {
  dialog.open();
}

var oDModel = new ODataModel(kmURL, {
  json: true
});
oDModel.setDefaultBindingMode(sap.ui.model.BindingMode.OneWay);
table.setModel(oDModel);
var mParams = {
  path: "/DocumentQuerySet",
  template: template,
};
table.bindAggregation("items", mParams);
```

I think that bindAggregation internally refreshes the model which forces the table to rerender after every data call. How can I avoid the model to refresh/rerender the table so that it does not scroll to the top every time the user scrolls down to see more data.

Appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could fix this problem by placing the Table control within a ScrollContainer. The [ScrollContainer](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ScrollContainer.html) will handle the growing feature of the table, which causes the change in height of the control. This will retain the current position without moving back to the top.

```
....
var table = new sap.m.Table({
            width: "100%",
            inset: true,
            growing: true,
            growingThreshold: 100,
            growingScrollToLoad: true
        })

        var oScroll = new sap.m.ScrollContainer({
            width: "100%",
            height: "500px",
            vertical: true,
            content: table
        })

        dialog.addContent(oScroll);
  ....
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen, Works like a charm